# ViewPropTypes 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package issue react-native + expo

Tags: react-native

I try to compile my react native app using npm run start (expo) to test my application after an upgrade from SDK v47 to v50 in my Android device, but I receive an error regarding to library that another one depends, I don't know who, any of you knows how to handle it?

This is the error that i get when app it's starting but break in this

```
ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.
```

[![Capture of my console][1]][1]

I already have the patch file generated, this is the configuration:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]